# How to "find" this Button with Selenium?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i´d like to click this button in my webdriver window with selenium. Most of the time i am using find_element_by_id, but how can I locate this one?

```
<button role="button" data-testid="uc-accept-all-button" class="sc-gsDKAQ cYtWkK" style="margin: 4px 0px;">accept all</button>
```

Tried xpath, name and class already like below

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='accept all']")).click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name("sc-gsDKAQ cYtWkK").click()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code you have already tried.

Comment: by what property or value would you like to select?

Comment: @ITgoldman its a cookie accept Button i just want to accept automaticlx

Answer (score 0):

I would go with this:

```js
document.querySelector("[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']").click();
```

```html
<button role="button" data-testid="uc-accept-all-button" class="sc-gsDKAQ cYtWkK" style="margin: 4px 0px;" onclick="console.log('thank you')">accept all</button>
```

For use by Selenium: (not tested but should work)

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']");
```

Comment: but what about your second code snippet? I cant modify the html code from the website.
what you think i should do with the second one?
thanks a lot

Comment: It's the same snippet in a way. Just use the first one it is good for the given HTML

Comment: okay and what about the document? Is this something to import or should I repace it with the variable of my driver?